# ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2019: how to set up Web.Debug and Web.Release if you have configSource in Web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, visual-studio-2019, xdt-transform

In my ASP.NET web form, this is what my connection string looks like in my Web.config file:

`<connectionStrings configSource="MySecrets.config"/>`

I know that I can use Web.Debug and Web.Release to change the connection strings so that they are not exposed when the web app is released.

However, the examples provided by Visual Studio mention:

```
In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
"connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" 
    connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However, this references a `<connectionStrings>` section in the Web.config file that I don't have in the first place, because in my project I have:

`<connectionStrings configSource="MySecrets.config"`

How can I set up the Web.Release to replace the `MySecrets.config` file so that it's not visible once published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the preprocessor to switch between connectionstring, for this you should have both connectionstrings.

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Project.Properties.Settings.ConnString_A" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Project.Properties.Settings.ConnString_B" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

code behind

```
public SqlConnection conn { get; set; }
public DbContext()
{
#if DEBUG
    conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnString_A);
#else
    conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnString_B);
#endif
}
```

reference: [#if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: Not sure how this can help me to be honest. How does this affect my Web.Debug and Web.Release files I don't see it.

Comment: this is something that I use, with this I don't have to use web.debug and web.release, I simply select the "Release" or "Debug" working environment

Comment: Ok, but how do you make sure you don't commit those strings to source control?